# converting ios safari compatible webapp into native

Tags: web-applications, cordova, iphone-web-app

My webapp does not use any of the api of phonegap.So I did't want to include the libraries of it.Can I use phonegap by deleting all the libraries or I should use UIWebView.Or is there another library available for converting safari compatible webapp into native app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that is not available right now. At least not for iOS. It might be for Android.

According to the PhoneGap roadmap, this functionality is coming.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28291160/roadmap-planning